# unescaping some HTML tags after they've been escaped for XSS

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, xss

I have html stored in the database and I need to output it to the page.

- If I don't escape() it, then I get the **bold** formatting I want, but  I run the risk of getting an XSS from the unescaped html source.
- If I escape() it, then it shows the raw html code `<b>bold text</b>` instead of **bold text**.

How can I escape everything, except some tags? I'm thinking to apply the escape(), then search for the `<b>` and `</b>` and unescape them. Would that work? Any security problems you see with it? I'm also not sure how I would search for the `<b></b>` tags. Regex for that maybe or what?

P.S. the escape() I mean is a function in Zend. I believe it's the equivalent of `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unescaping is the way to go. If you only *whitelist* a couple of tags to be converted back from the html escapes, then you won't run into XSS exploits.

Workaround markups provide no advantage regarding that, as the many failed BBcode parsers prove.

(Instead of converting back and forth it might however be sensible to utilize HTMLPurifier instead.)

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML-markup in the database comes from users you do not trust, you should give them access to [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or similar 'safe' editing environments, so they can prepare the markup they want and not be allowed to inject HTML.

Attempts to perform selective filtering are frequently wrong, and miss ways attackers can inject malicious code. So don't let them write raw HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars_decode()` is the opposite of `htmlspecialchars()`. It is possible to unescape it, but there's no parameter for restricting tags.

If the `html` is written by the user it is **bad idea :)**

Comment: This is why I was thinking not to use the exact reverse of `htmlspecialchars()` and to use a custom function that would unescape only the tags I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTMLPurifier library which will take care of everything you need to do with escaping and such. Here is a nice  video explaining how to install it into the zend framework

http://www.zendcasts.com/htmlpurifier-integration/2011/05/

Answer (score 1):

try use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) in the second parameter is the $ allowable_tags

Answer (score 1):

Use **Zend_Filter_StripTags** class and as argument for the constructor use an array with following keys:

1. 'allowTags'     => Tags which are allowed
2. 'allowAttribs'  => Attributes which are allowed

This second part allows you to trim all unwanted attribs like 'onClick' etc whose can be as dangerous as `<script>` code, but you can leave 'src' for `<img>` or 'href' for `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Create your own view helper or you can also use setEscape() in controller See  http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html#zend.view.scripts.escaping